# Non-resizable windows with windowStyle=None

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window

Basically, I want to create a window that looks like the following:
[alt text http://www.thex9.net/screenshots/2009-10-15_1347.png](http://www.thex9.net/screenshots/2009-10-15_1347.png)

However, the window shouldn't be resizable (the one in the screenshot is) but must retain the glass border. The XAML for the window in the screenshot is as follows:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window" Title="MainWindow" WindowStyle="None">    
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"/>
</Window>
```

Is it possible to create a window which looks similar to the one in my screenshot but is not resizable? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This answer of mine may help guide you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469727/creating-custom-forms-in-wpf/1469737#1469737

Answer (score 30):

Probably you can get desired result by: 
    **[ResizeMode=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms589725(v=VS.100,d=hv.2).aspx)**
XAML object property which can take have following states:

- NoResize - A window cannot be resized. The Minimize and Maximize buttons are not displayed in the title bar.
- CanMinimize - A window can only be minimized and restored. The Minimize and Maximize buttons are both shown, but only the Minimize button is enabled.
- CanResize - A window can be resized. The Minimize and Maximize buttons are both shown and enabled.
- CanResizeWithGrip - A window can be resized. The Minimize and Maximize buttons are both shown and enabled. A resize grip appears in the bottom-right corner of the window.

Answer (score 22):

One way to accomplish a fixed size Window while retaining the border is to set the Min[Width|Height] and Max[Width|Height] properties to be the same value. The border will still show the resize cursor, but the user will not be able to change the size of the Window.

If the fact that the border still indicates that it's resizable bothers you, the next step is to set the ResizeMode="NoResize", but then you have to start drawing your own Aero glass if you want to retain the glass edges.

Comment: Is there a way to intercept windows messages to stop the cursor from being changed when the mouse is over the border?

Comment: Well, I know you can [hook the Windows message loop][1], so you might want to look into that. Honestly I'm not sure what messages to watch for to be able to intercept interaction with the Window chrome or if you even can for that matter.

[1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/nickkramer/archive/2006/03/18/554235.aspx