# are there skins/themes for WinForms .NET?

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to establish an alternative graphic design for the winforms, is there a third-party tool or a ocx control that allows me to do this?

thank you very much for your help and of course your time.

Comment: Maybe Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) is something for you. It provides a better and easier way to add theming support to an application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I give professional look and feel to my .NET windows application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962934/how-do-i-give-professional-look-and-feel-to-my-net-windows-application)

Answer (score 2):

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) has [awesome ones](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/), trivial to code up as well. Highly recommended.

You can create your own skins as well, either start from scratch or use a built in one and modify.

The one thing that may or may not be a problem for you is that their skins work with their controls only.  It's a very complete library, so it's worth switching your forms, IMO. the only thing hard to switch may be controls you write yourself, you need to make the look and feel match the designed skin for the other controls.

Comment: I have been using DevExpress Winforms controls and their themes for quite some time.  The main word of warning is if you use their layout controls and there are forms with lots of controls, your form will render much slower than if you use standard controls.  The themes are quite intensive in terms of graphics.  They look great but just be aware.

Comment: Commercial warning. This'll cost you. Unless I'm very much mistaken.