# Personalized windows form and controls?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, personalization

I wanted to make my own windows style, borders, controls for close, minimize, maximize, etc.

I was looking around with terms like "custom windows form", "personalized windows form", "custom controls" but it did not helped very much to find what I am looking for.

I would like to know what should I be looking for if I want to maky my own windows form design and controls ?

Are there libraries to make this easier ?

PS: I am sorry if this question looks too abroad I am still not sure how to simplificate it.

Comment: WPF lends itself more toward this approach. You could try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752299.aspx

Comment: @SteveCav I never used WPF yet but it seems quiet nice, what can be easyly done inside the form but I am more interesting about changing the window outer border and controls could you possible show me an example of that in WPF ?

Comment: Good old stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469727/creating-custom-forms-in-wpf

Comment: Pretty good topic, thanks Steve will make sure to check that one, I was hoping to have more simple options for windows forms too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently found http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/ which seems pretty nice and easy to deal with and since i got no other replies of ways to acomplish this and this library was the on I liked the most from the recommendations I got im answering with it and checking as the answer, if in the future some one post another option that is better and easier then what I currently have I will consider it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the look of your form and controls try [DotNetSkin](http://www.dotnetskin.net/). You can make from existing windows themes or your own controls by modifying it.